# Restoring Incoming Emails STMP Drop Folder

Tags: 2013, document-library, 2019, incoming-email

Working in SharePoint 2019.  After configuring the incoming emails and restarting the timer job the emails that were in my Drop Folder are GONE.  They are not in the SharePoint Library and not in the Drop Folder.

Is there a way to restore the emails that use to be in the Drop Folder?

I am regretting going to SharePoint 2019.  I am reading that configuration for incoming email SMTP does not work the same as it had done in 2013 or 2016.

Comment: Site Collection recycle bin?

Comment: @willman Thanks. No they are not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When there is an issue or the SMTP alias doesn't match any configured Document Library, the files in the drop folder are permanently deleted by the timer service.